# Reference a parent resource inside a module using bicep while parent has not deployed yet?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I'm trying to deploy a child module in bicep but I get not found error as its parent has not been deployed yet.

This is the parent bicep code:

```
@description('The name of the app service. full site name will be DT-xxx-Open')
param site_name string
var full_site_name = 'DT-${site_name}-Open'

@description('Resource location')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

resource app 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' = {
  kind: 'app'
  name: full_site_name
  location: location
  ...
}

module site_config 'modules/appservice-config.bicep' = {
  name: 'site_config'
  params: {
    resource_name: full_site_name
    resource_location: location
  }
}
```

this is my module bicep file:

```
  @description('Resource name')
  param resource_name string

  (error happens at this line) resource site_name_resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' existing = {
    name: resource_name
  }

  resource site_name_logs 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2021-02-01' = {
    parent: site_name_resource
    name: 'logs'
    ...
}
```

But the problem is I'm getting a **not found** error as its parent service deployment has not been completed yet and if I retry then it will work fine!

I wonder, is there any way to run this module after completing its parent deployment?

Comment: Could you share how you invoke this module? Bicep supports implicit dependency or you could always add a `dependsOn` explicitly

Comment: The problem is we can't use `dependsOn` when we are using `existing`. using `existing` means the resource is already there and we can use it, while in this case it has not been created yet.

Comment: `existing` keyword is just here to translate to a `reference, resourceId`. If this module is invoked with `dependsOn` on the parent it will work, please share more code :-)

Comment: Parent code is:  `resource app 'Microsoft.... {} module site_config 'modules/appservice-config.bicep' = { name: '...' params: {resource_name: 'parent_name' ... }}`. after calling the module I get not found error as the parent resource which has been passed as a parameter has not been deployed yet.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Just added the full parent code to the question.

Comment: Oh, I should have added `dependsOn` in the parent file. Thanks @Thomas now it's working. Could you please add your solution as an answer so I can mark it as done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to add a `dependsOn` when invoking you module.
Bicep use [implicit dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/resource-dependencies#implicit-dependency) So you can use the parent resource name as parameter for you module:

```bicep
module site_config 'module.bicep' = {
  name: 'site_config'
  params: {
    resource_name: app.name
    ...
  }
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```bicep
module site_config 'module.bicep' = {
  name: 'site_config'
  params: {
    resource_name: full_site_name
  }
  dependsOn: [ app ]
}
```